# FirebaseFirestore delete() function when called from 2 clients at the same time gives success in both clients

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In my case, a document (say C) is deleted from a collection, say PQR.

I call the following the following piece of code in 2 clients A and B simultaneously.

```
 db.collection("PQR").document("C").delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

        }
    });
```

The `onSuccess()` in both the clients is called after the delete.

How is this possible, since according to me only one of the clients should be able to delete the document and the onSuccess of either client A or client B should be called.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The `onSuccess` listener is called for an operation if the intended result of the operation was accomplished, which in the case of `delete()` means that `onSuccess` is called if the document doesn't exist after the operation. It doesn't matter for that if the call actively deleted the document, or if the document didn't exist before the call.

If you want to detect if a specific call deletes the document, you'll need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for the operation.