# How to know if a specific call deleted a document in FirebaseFirestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have written a transaction like this:

```
db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = transaction.get(deleteRef);
                if(documentSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    transaction.delete(deleteRef);    
                }
            return null;
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // implement logic
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
         @Override
         public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

Now, when 2 clients A and B run this transaction simultaneously, according to this code, only one can be successful and the corresponding logic will be implemented.

But, unfortunately this transaction is failing due to the following error:

> Every document read in a transaction must also be written.

Kindly help, thanks.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180270/421195 (note Javascript vs. Android/Java, but same principle...)

Comment: It might help to know that this question is a follow up to https://stackoverflow.com/q/58159635, where I suggested using transactions if you must know which exact call is deleting the document. If both client A and client B run the transaction, do both of them get this error message? Or only the one who runs after the other client has deleted the document already?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want the transaction to fail as indicated (since it was in a state where a document update should not happen).  First, consider just ignoring the message, since that tells you why the transaction didn't succeed, and you know that's not a problem.

Second, if you don't like that error message, try throwing an new unchecked exception (e.g. RuntimeException) from your transaction handler in the circumstance where no changes should be made to the document previously read.  You might get a new error message in the task error handler, but the result will be the same - no changes made to any documents.

Comment: Hi Doug, I want the transaction to succeed exactly once. When the document exists, I want to delete it. But even that is not happening and the transaction is failing.